# Compare time using Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel application I want to compare times 
If time was greater than 23:30 and less than 6:00 returns true
else return false

```
$time1 = strtotime('23:30:00');
$time2 = strtotime('06:00:00');
$time3 = strtotime('01:30:00');

if ($time3>=$time1 && $time2>$time1 ) {
    var_dump('yes');
}
else {
    var_dump('no');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `Carbon` to compare date and datetime values:

```
$time1 = Carbon::createFromTimeString('23:30:00');
$time2 = Carbon::createFromTimeString('06:00:00');
$time3 = Carbon::createFromTimeString('01:30:00');

if ($time3->gte($time1) && $time2->gt($time1)) {
    var_dump('yes');
} else {
    var_dump('no');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Carbon`, it has functionality to create from a certain format, with the `createFromFormat()` method.

```
$time1 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '23:30:00');

$time2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '06:00:00');

$time3 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '01:30:00');
```

`Carbon` has comparisons in built, with `gt()` being greater than and `lt()` being less than. Adding an e to the call as `lte()` would be less than equals. Or you can be more explicit, look through this section in the [documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison).

```
if ($time3->gte($time1) && $time2->gt($time1)) {
    //
}
else {
    //
}
```